# Warning: array_combine() error message

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting this error message on a client site:

> Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in /home/siennahomes/public_html/wp-content/themes/realhomes-child/property-details/property-floorplan.php on line 945

Line 945 is:

```
$details = array_combine($fplan2_dimensions_titles, $fplan2_dimensions_values);
```

The full block of php is:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($fplan2_dimensions_titles)){
    $fplan2_dimensions_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_fplan2_dimensions_values', true);
    if (!empty($fplan2_dimensions_values)){
    $details = array_combine($fplan2_dimensions_titles, $fplan2_dimensions_values);

    echo '<ul class="additional-details clearfix">';
    foreach ($details as $title => $value){
?>
```

I'm still getting use to PHP and so everywhere I've looked doesn't make sense to me. So that's why I'm asking, the code I'm working with is set up differently to most examples I've found on the subject.

Other parts of the page use exact same coding and it still works perfectly fine, It's just one particular part that doesn't, I don't understand.

On another note, I'm also getting this error too:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/siennahomes/public_html/wp-content/themes/realhomes-child/property-details/property-floorplan.php on line 948

948 is in the code above it's this part

```
foreach($details as $title => $value ){
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is the content of the arrays you are combining ?

Comment: do you mean the code or whats in the data. They're just room specs

Comment: I mean if you print $fplan2_dimensions_titles and $fplan2_dimensions_values , what is data stored in these arrays

Comment: I understand now, it was missing a garage size in the wordpress side of things. Which is on the clients fault not mine. Now I understand what it means by equal. Would there be a way for combine arrays to work without equal measurements? Or should I just leave it up for the client to fill in all the data inputs?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is  that your array are not equals. Should have the same length because array_combine will do that:

```
$carsMake = array('Ford','Mercedes','BMW');
$carsModel = array('Focus','180C','320');
```

So when we call array_combine() function

```
$carsMakeModel = array_combine($carsMake,$carsModel)
print_r($carsMakeModel)
```

will output:

```
Array([Ford] => Focus,[Mercedes] => 180C, [BMW] => 320)
```

Is a solution to turn off the PHP warnings, but i don't recommend this. See why this array are not equals and check if the arrays is equals before you call this function.

```
if(count($carsMake) == count($carsModel){
    array_combine($carsMake,$carsModel);
}
```

Comment: but I don't understand what is needing to be equal. and equal in what way? This is also calling data from wordpress so if the data need to be equal that might not be possible. I don't understand anything in your example

Comment: never mind, I understand the whole equals part now. I figured out what was causing the problem, yes you're right (I just still don't understand php terminology which is why I was confused). On the client side of things, they simply missed a garage measurement in the wordpress cms under properties.Would there be a way for combine arrays to work without equal measurements? Or should I just leave it up for the client to fill in all the data inputs?

Comment: Yes, you can combine the arrays without array_combine() function. 

`$carsMake = array('Ford','Mercedes','BMW');
$carsModel = array('Focus','180C','320');
$combinedArray = array();
for($i = 0; $ <= count($carsMake; $i++){
    $combinedArray[$carsMake[$i]] = $carsModel[$i]
}`

Answer (score 1):

The size of your array values must be equal, because you are going to use other array as key and the other as values.

For example

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

if happens that a data from one of your array is not equal with other one create an empy values to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

**Errors/Exceptions**

Throws E_WARNING if the number of elements in keys and values does not match.

[**Look this**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)